# Double-quote mark in Figure caption

Tags: graphics, captions

I'm incorporating figures in my document using the `graphicx` and `caption` packages.  The caption appears as, eg, `Figure"1`, with a double-quote mark between the word and the number.  It appears even when I change the word Figure to **Fig.**, by the command

```
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},labelformat={default},
                      labelsep=period,name={Fig.}}
```

How can I get rid of the double-quote mark?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use? Not all document classes are fully compatible with the `caption` package... For sure, I am unable to reproduce the issue you report if I use the `article` document class.

Comment: I have tracked down the problem.  It arises from the use of a macro to ensure that close-quote marks don't appear instead of open-quote marks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's query got resolved based on information not made available.